# User's Entity DbContext corrupted by another user when simultaneous requests

Tags: c#, entity-framework, dbcontext

My project use Entity Framerwork 6. There is 1 website for "n" similar Database. The user can switch from a database to another.

```
 //-> Unit of Work and repositories
_currentContainer.RegisterType(typeof(ItrsEntities), new PerRequestLifetimeManager(), new InjectionConstructor());
_currentContainer.RegisterType(typeof(ItrsEntitiesWrapper), new InjectionConstructor(_currentContainer));

_currentContainer.RegisterType<IWorkshopRepository, WorkshopRepository>();
_currentContainer.RegisterType<IIndexRepository, IndexRepository>();
```

The problem occures when two users click at the same time. The second user "corrupts" the `DbContext` from the first user who click.

It's manifested by :

- > The ObjectContext instance has been disposed and can no longer be used for operations that require a connection.
- > The operation cannot be completed because the DbContext has been disposed.
- ... lot's of random error

An other strange manifestation of the problem:

- The first user get data of the second user (data from another database). It's like the second user replace the DbContext of the first one...

ItrsEntities is the DbContext. For explain what is a user for me, during my test I use two differents computer, and two different Windows account. I'm not in local, I have deployed the website on a server. (in local no problem because I'm alone).

I'm using PerRequestLifetimeManager. I think it's a problem of implementation but no way to find where is the problem.
Thanks in advance,

Comment: Sounds like you have a scoping issue. DbContexts on a server should be limited per user request (or at least per user session). It sounds like whenever you create/register the DbContext it is not scoped correctly

Comment: You forgot to tell us what class is the DbContext... I'm guessing ItrsEntities bit it's nice to be sure.

Comment: Also, what is a 'user' here? How do you test?

Comment: Which DI tool are you using?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are keeping a Context around for the life of the application, which is a pretty serious anti-pattern.  It can lead to all kinds of errors, as you are seeing in your code, especially when multiple threads get involved.  The recommended pattern is to create a new Context for each "logical unit of work", preferably surrounded by a `using` block.

Contexts are fairly cheap to construct, but they tend to collect "cruft" the longer they are opened and reused due to caching, which can seriously slow down your application.  By keeping the Context's lifetime short you will minimize this effect and isolate logical operations from each other, making things much easier to debug.

Comment: There is a PerRequestLifetimeManager in there, we just can't tell if it is used correctly.